# CONCAT Function in SQLite : Error - SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: CONCAT)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to CONCAT the DATA FROM my EMPLOYEE TABLE

```
TABLE EMPLOYEE 
============================================== 
empno ename   Job           salary    deptno
----------------------------------------------
101   Roy     Programmer    5000      20
102   Todd    Analyst       6000      10
105   Leslie  Analyst       5500      20
107   Cindy   Developer     7200      30
```

with these queries

```
SELECT CONCAT(ename || 'is getting paid' || salary || 'for' || job)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE empno = 101;
-- and 
SELECT CONCAT(ename, 'is getting paid', salary, 'for', job)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE empno = 101;
```

But both result in the error:

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: CONCAT)'

Expected Output:

> "Roy is getting paid 5000 for Programmer"

Please assist!

Answer (score 5):

Use the concatenation operator `||` to concatenate strings. (As you actually already did.)

```
SELECT ename || ' is getting paid ' || salary || ' for ' || job
FROM employees
WHERE empno = 101;
```

The [search result for concat](https://sqlite.com/search?s=d&q=concat) in the sqlite documenation did not return any meaningfull hits.

- There is an [opcode](https://sqlite.com/opcode.html#the_opcodes) with the name concat.
- In [operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes) this is written:

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings
> of its operands

So it seems that there is no function `concat()`. But as mentionend above the operator `||` can be used.